# Pack tkinter window expanding past frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI that I'm trying to lay out so the screen words are added to fills the screen in each direction, but only up to the size of root.geometry('300x600')

Instead, it is expanding far past the width of the frame. Is there any way to size this so it packs correct? I have tried a lot of things so far that don't work.

**Edit: To see the entire text, and scroll bar, I have to set root.geometry('684x418)**

```
from tkinter import *

class Rhapsody_Gui:
    def __init__(self,root):
        Window = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)

        self.InWidget = Text(Window,bg='white',bd=3,fg='black',exportselection=0,height=1,wrap=WORD,insertofftime=0,insertbackground="white")

        Window.pack()
        self.InWidget.focus_set()



        self.scroll = Scrollbar(Window, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.OutWidget = Text(Window, yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)#, height=30)
        self.OutWidget.bind("<Button 1>",self.Select)
        self.InWidget.bind("<Return>", self.Post)
        myList = ['words', 'that', 'should', 'be', 'printed']
        for x in myList:
            self.OutWidget['state'] = ['normal']
            self.OutWidget.insert(END, x +'\n')

        self.scroll.config(command=self.OutWidget.yview)
        self.InWidget.pack(side=TOP, fill='none')
        self.OutWidget.pack(side=LEFT, fill='none', expand=False)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.OutWidget.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=False)#, ipadx=5)
        self.OutWidget['state'] = ['disabled']

    def Post(self,event):
        text = self.InWidget.get(1.0,2.0)
        self.InWidget.delete(1.0,2.0)
        self.OutWidget['state'] = ['normal']
        self.OutWidget.insert('end',text)
        self.OutWidget['state'] = ['disabled']
        return ("break")

    def Select(self,event):
        line_start = self.OutWidget.index("@%s,%s linestart" % (event.x, event.y))
        line_end = self.OutWidget.index("%s lineend" % line_start)
        self.OutWidget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")
        self.OutWidget.tag_remove("highlight", 1.0, "end")
        self.OutWidget.tag_add("highlight", line_start, line_end)
        self.InWidget.focus_set()
        return ("break")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x600+600+100')
    App = Rhapsody_Gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**This is what I want it to look like, except filled all the way to the bottom**
[image: This is what I want it to look like, except extended all the way to the bottom]

Comment: Are you asking how to make the Text widget fill the window or make the window shrink to the size of the Text widget? The window draws at 600x300 for me. Add this line to see the geometry when it changes: `root.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: print(root.geometry()))`

Comment: I want the OutWidget which is where the text is written, to be the same size as the overall window. For me, it is extending invisibly far past the width of the frame. So, I have to resize the window to be larger to see the scroll bar or the edge of the OutWidget text window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly set the OUtWidget to `fill='none', expand=False`. But from your description you want:

```
self.OutWidget.pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand=True)
```

You need start with a tiny Text window because it will only expand, not shrink:

```
self.OutWidget = Text(Window, height=1, width=1, yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
```

and make sure you do the same for the containing Frame:

```
Window.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

Specifying the size for Window is pointless because those setting are overridden as soon as anything is packed into it.

Comment: I've tried setting the side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True. What I was missing apparently, was the need to set the window height=1,width=1. For some reason, even with the window set to fill and expand, it doesn't work. Any idea why the height, and width need to be set small explicitely?

Comment: @ProfessionalNameForDisplayHere I tested it and it worked for me. Update your OP with the code you have now and I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. It does work, but only if I also specify the height=1, width=1. Without that part. The window expands out past the width of the gui window.

Answer (score -2):

Use `<window/parent>.resizable(width=False, height=True)`.

Comment: To make your answer feasible for this site, you better _explain_ how to solve the problem, instead of simply posting blind code.